# How to substitute awk argument?

Tags: awk, parameter

I want simplify awk command for common usage so instead of writing `awk '{print "rm -r"$4 }'` each time I want to write `myawk "rm -r"$4`.
I've tried to write such function

`myawk() { awk '{ print $1 }' }` and it dosn't work..

How can I write function such that in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

To pass a string from a shell script to an embedded awk script, use an awk variable and the `-v` argument.

```
myawk () {
  awk -v mystring="$1" '{ print mystring }'
}
```

Another possibility is to put the string in an environment variable and access it through the `ENVIRON` array.

Answer (score 1):

Try using double quotes instead of single. 
http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html

Or writing it this way:

```
myawk () { awk '{print '"$1"' }'; }
```

But I can see a lot of bad side effects with trying to include raw user strings.  For example:

```
myawk '"hello"; system("echo there")"
```

This would get evaluated as `awk '{print "hello"; system("echo there") }'`, which may display "hello" and "there; but more malicious commands could be sent if not escaped properly.

Answer (score -1):

What about adding `alias awk="awk '{print $1 }'"` to your .bashrc file?